# minimum no of integers of the form 2^l required

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit

I came across this problem today, in this we have been given a sorted array `a[]` in ascending order and then we find sum of the numbers `2a1, 2a2, 2a3, ..., 2an` and  we need to find the minimum number of additional integers of the type `2l` (`l` is non-negative) that must be required  such that the sum total of all integers present equals `2k - 1` for some integer `k` (`k` is non-negative).

For example:

The input consists of an integer n in first line. The second input line contains n space-separated integers a(1), a(2), ..., a(n).

Example 1:
3
0 1 2

The answer in this case is 0 since 2<sup>0</sup>+2<sup>1</sup>+2<sup>2</sup> = 7 is already in the form of 2<sup>k</sup>-1 for k=3.

Example 2:
3
2 4 5

the answer for this case is 3 since 2<sup>2</sup>+2<sup>4</sup>+2<sup>5</sup>=52 and to make it of 2<sup>k</sup>-1 we have 63 so required 2<sup>0</sup>,2<sup>1</sup>,2<sup>3</sup> as the three term.

I approached this problem to find the sum and then count the number of 1's in the binary representation and then answer equals `max(a[i])-count`.

But the problem that I get is the given constraints in the problem
1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5
0 ≤ a[i] ≤ 2*10^9

Can someone help?
This problem i got in a programming contest and solutions accepted in 2.6 MB memory.
So,Storing or taking array bits of 2*10^9 bits would not be better.There will be a different approach or idea i think.

Comment: Is this a programming problem or a mathematical algorithm question?

Comment: @Barmer Hi,I think it is algorithmic problem based on bits :)

Comment: Hi Raunak, if the array elements are 2,2,2, then the answer is one, right? Just asking to understand the concept.

Comment: Why are these constraints bothering you? Does your algorithm stop working under these conditions?

Comment: @n.m. Hi,we can't hold the value 2^(10^9) in any data type say i am using c for this. i think there could be other approach to solve this that i am at present not able to think.So i need help. :)

Comment: @JERRY-the chuha Hi, No,in your example 2^2+2^2+2^2=12 so to get 15(2^4-1) we require 3 and for that 2^1+2^0 so answer should be 2 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 2*10^9 bits of memory to solve this problem. The boundary on n (n < 10^5) suggest another solution:

(1) Sort the `a_i` :

`3 3 3 3 3 5 7 9`

(2) Get rid of the duplicates by finding consecutive copies via binary search. In this case, you have `5` (`=101` in binary), so `3 3 3 3 3` turns into `3 5`. Your `a_i` are now `3 5 5 7 9`. (Note that this is equivalent to adding numbers in binary, but it's more efficient since you know that your numbers have up to 10^9 bits but at max 10^5 bits are set!)

(3) Repeat step 2 until you no longer have duplicates. In this example you only need another step, you end up with `3 6 7 9`.

(4) Calculate `max(a_i) - number of a_i left + 1`. This is your result, in this case `9-4+1=6`.

---

Possible implementation of step (2) :

The first thing I would try is overwriting from the beginning, but keeping a pointer to check where I am at the moment, so: You read `3`. You binary search for the last `3` and keep a pointer to the following element. You then overwrite: `3 3 3 3 3 5 7 9` -> `3 5 x x x *5 7 9` (it doesn't matter what's at the `x` positions, and the pointer is now at the `5`). Now, for a first solution, simply copy everything from the end to make it contiguous again: `3 5 5 7 9` and remember that your array is now shorter.

This is *not* the most efficient solution as it will lead to a lot of copying if you have an array like `3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6...`, but it should be decent enough.

For better performance, you could only do step (1) and then insert everything into a hashmap that maps `a_i` to the number of times it appears, and then operate on that hashmap. That's pretty fast for your constraints, but implementing a hashmap in C isn't trivial.

Comment: Yes,sir your idea looks good but i find difficulty in implementing the step 2. Can you help me in that i am using C.

Comment: I have added some comments regarding the implementation and a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to work with bit arrays.

You need a<sub>i</sub> <= 2*10<sup>9</sup> (2 billion). To represent 2 billion bits, you need about 256MB of memory (every byte stores 8 bits). You may need to create some convenient abstraction layer that will provide functions like `.get(int n)`, `.set(int n)` which will read and save bits in that bit array.

---

To allocate array, use `malloc`:

```
typedef byte unsigned char;
// 256MB, enough for 2 billion bits
byte * bit_array = malloc(256*1024*1024);

// or use calloc, which initializes to 0:
byte * bit_array = calloc(256*1024*1024, 1);
```

To set bit n, use this assignment:

```
bit_array[n/8] |= 1 << (n % 8);
```

To get bit n, use this expression:

```
(bit_array[n/8] >> (n % 8)) & 1
```

---

You algorithm could be something like this:

- Create bit array of desired maximum length all 1 set.
- Loop through all a<sub>i</sub> and set i-th bit in that bit array to 0.
- Count how many bits are still set to 1. That is your answer.

Comment: Hi,sir i am using C language i got your idea but the problem i face is that how to represent 2 billion bits ,i can not take an array of a[2*10^9]. Plz help me or give an idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It is very simple: `unsigned char * bit_array = malloc(256*1024*1024);` will allocate byte array of 256MB size. This is enough to keep 2 billion bits

Comment: But one more problem sir if suppose no's are equal say 2,2,2 then ur solution may not work i think.

Comment: yes, I assume that a<sub>i</sub> are unique. If they are not, I guess you could converge them to higher order beforehand. For example `2^3 + 2^3 = 2^4`

Comment: answer updated to provide methods for allocating and manipulating with bit arrays

Comment: Convergence will become so complicated i think of say 2^2,2^2,2^2,2^2,2^2 comes they will converge to 2^3,2^3,2^2 and then to 2^4,2^2 so how could i achieve this conversion in c sir.Since it's not at one level.

Comment: Actually, it is very simple to do. Instead of setting bits, you add them. For this, you will need to implement adding 1 (starting from position n) to your bit array (with carry-over).